# Can you grant groups access to the TFS administration console instead of users?

Tags: tfs

I'm updating the users that have access to the TFS admin console, and it appears to only let you add individual user accounts.  Is there any way for me to choose Active Directory groups instead of users?

Answer (score 0):

In TFS 2012 and TFS 2013 in the settings for TFS groups on the security page when you click on "Add..." in the "Members" tab, you get the options to either select a "TFS group" or a "Windows User or group".

If you don't see these two options, it can be that TFS 2010 has a different security mechanism that I don't know of or your Sharepoint Server hasn't been added to the AD yet.